# AspectJ compiler doesn compile *.aj files

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

I have the following project:

```
root
   |---pom.xml

src/main/java
   |---com.package
          |----App.java

src/main/aspects
   |---com.package
          |----Trace.aj
```

Now, the pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aspectj-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <ajdtBuildDefFile>build.ajproperties</ajdtBuildDefFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After executing `mvn aspectj:compile` I got only the `App.class` compiled class, but didn't `Trace.class`. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1):

By default the aspectj-maven-plugin expects the aspects in the directory `src/main/aspect`. If you want to store them in a different directory, you have to specify the configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
</configuration>
```